# jQuery .animate does not work

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I am not sure why but one of the divs, .load_post, but .blog_posts does not animate. I cannot figure out why. Here is my code:

page1.php (main page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<?php
include 'body/head.php';
?>

<body>
<?php
    include 'body/nav.php';
?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.blog_posts').load('blog_feed.php');
    });
</script>

<div style="position:absolute; top:90px; left:1px; width:550px; background-color:lightblue;">

    <h1>Blog Posts</h1>

    <div class="blog_posts">

    </div>

    <div class="load_post" style="position:absolute; top:250px; left:1500px; width:550px; background-color:lightblue;">

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

page2.php (loads, and animates the divs)

```
<?php

mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('awsomechat');

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `blog`");

?>

<?php
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

$id = $rows['id'];
$date = str_replace("-", "/", $rows['date']);
$title = stripslashes($rows['title']);

?>
<a href="#" class="post" rel="<?php echo $id; ?>"> <h2 style="padding:0px; margin:0px;"><?php echo $title; ?></h2></a>
<h6 style="padding:0px; margin:0px;"><?php echo $date; ?></h6>
<?php
}
?>

<script>
$('.post').click(function() {       
var value = $(this).attr('rel');

$('.load_post').html('Loading...').load('load_post.php?value='+value);
$('load_post').animate({"left": "-=1500px"}, "slow");
$('.blog_posts').animate({"left": "-=1500px"}, "slow");

});
</script>
```

page3.php (loads a post selected)

```
<?php

mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('awsomechat');

$post = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_GET['value']));

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `blog` WHERE `id` = $post");

$rows = mysql_fetch_array($query);

?>
<div class="loaded_post">

<h2 style="padding:0px; margin:0px;"><?php echo stripslashes($rows['title']); ?></h2>
<h6 style="padding:0px; margin:0px;"><?php echo str_replace("-", "/", $rows['date']); ?></h6>
<p><?php echo stripslashes($rows['text']); ?></p>

</div>
```

Can anyone see a problem of why .blog_posts is not animating? I cannot figure it out of why it is not moving to the left.

Comment: Seems like you're asking a jQuery question, why 90% of it is php/mysql then? Try to isolate the problem, get the minimum of rendered HTML to reproduce the issue and throw it in a http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com

Comment: you have a typo at load posts forgot the .

Comment: Your missing a period $('load_post').animate({"left": "-=1500px"}, "slow");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to `page1.php` instead of `page2.php` so your JS looks like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.blog_posts').load('blog_feed.php');
    $(document).on('click', '.post', function() {       
        var value = $(this).attr('rel');
        $('.load_post').html('Loading...')
                       .load('load_post.php?value='+value, function(){
                            $(this).animate({"left": "-=1500px"}, "slow");
                            $('.blog_posts').animate({"left": "-=1500px"}, "slow");
                       });
    });
});
</script>
```

You should also make sure that `.blog_posts` has proper styling (maybe `position: absolute;` like `.load_post`) so that animating the `left` property does something.

Comment: Have you tried setting `.blog_posts` to `position: absolute;` like `.load_post`?

Comment: Yea there are no error messages showing. I added the js code that was posted here and removed the code from the other page also.

Comment: Sorry, I think I wrote another comment as you were responding. Maybe try adding `position: absolute;` with `top` and `left` properties to `.blog_posts` just like `.load_post`?

Answer (score 0):

Right now the `load_posts` shouldn't animate because you haven't selected it properly.  You need the `.` before it.  So `$('.load_post').animate({"left": "-=1500px"}, "slow");`

Comment: Right now it reads `$('load_post').animate({"left": "-=1500px"}, "slow");`  It should read `$('.load_post').animate({"left": "-=1500px"}, "slow");` with the `.` before the `load_post`.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the jQuery file.

Comment: jQuery is included in the head.php file

Answer (score -1):

After a quick view I think it needs to be without "px" in the animate function.
So replace `$('.blog_posts').animate({"left": "-=1500px"}, "slow");` with `$('.blog_posts').animate({"left": "-=1500"}, "slow");`

Comment: `.animate()` can be used with the "px", here's a demo from their docs: http://api.jquery.com/animate/#example-1